# Is there a way to pass a diagnostic message out of an OpenGL 2.0 ES shader on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

This question is specifically about OpenGL 2.0 ES on Android, but if there are more general answers based on the OpenGL specs, I'd be interested in those too.

Is there a way to pass a message (string) out of a GL 2.0 ES shader to the application code (either Java or native)?  E.g.

```
void main()
{
   ...
   if (somecondition)
   {
       logMessage("Things are messed up man");
   }
}
```

If not, why would a programming environment be defined (OpenGL ES 2.0 shader language in this case) without this type of facility?  I don't know anything about hardware but surely this would not be that hard to implement in the GPU.  If there are performance issues, it could always be optionally #ifdef'd out of the shader code...

Comment: Nicol could you tell me why you voted me down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no logging facilities like you're asking for in any of the OpenGL shading languages (including OpenGL ES).  Debug contexts on desktop OpenGL (and in ES when they get there) may provide some information, but there's nothing like what you're asking for.

The most common technique (and this is usually done in the context of fragment shaders) is to set the output of the shader to an error color, or some other signal that indicates the shader failed some condition you were banking on.

Given many instances of a particular shader execute simultaneously (think of how many fragment shader threads are executed when filling in a full-screen quad), tracking the state of each thread would require considerable amounts of state to do the job right.

You say:

> I don't know anything about hardware but surely this would not be that hard to implement in the GPU.

No; modern GPUs are complex machines with complex designs.  While doing this is possible, it's not worth the additional complexity and hardware validation.  That's the magic of APIs, while something like that looks conceptually simple, it's not.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer radical7.  I hadn't thought through the fact that the shaders are run many times per frame, and simultaneously at that.  I'm new to all this :).  Maybe one way around that would be to define the logging function so that only the first call per frame actually does anything.  That way it could be useful for proving diagnostics about error conditions that should logically never happen...

Comment: Forgive me for being pedantic but it's my nature.  I said it "would not be that hard" to implement this and I now retract that since I don't really know what I'm talking about:).  But still I don't know that it can be said, absolutely, that it's not worth the additional complexity.  The cost of implementing this (additional complexity, etc, like you said) may be arbitrarily high but it is finite.  So if the value to debugging is high enough, it would be a worthwhile trade-off.

Comment: @DavidStone You're very welcome.  Indeed you're right; it's possible, and it's something that application developers often request.  However, it's a difficult problem to solve (essentially, it's debugging a massively threaded program, and that's tough for CPUs as well), and it's impact on hardware pipelines could be troublesome.  Most modern GPUs (even in mobile devices) execute multiple threads in parallel and rely on most threads doing close to the same thing at the same time.  Debugging or early termination really affects performance.  Just keep asking nicely for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

radical7 answer is correct.

If you want to do debugging of the shader code, GPU vendors provide compilers and simulators. Or you could try the [glm library](http://glm.g-truc.net/) and code the shader in C++, with all the tools to print messages you need.